# The private beta length is hard-coded in the public beta announcement email

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, email

<sub>[Another place where the 7-day private beta duration was hard-coded…](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/overly-optimistic-beta-progress-indicator) Am I on a cosmetic bug report roll or what?</sub>

The e-mail announcing the beginning of a new public beta gets the duration of the private beta wrong:

> The new Cryptography Stack Exchange site is now open to the public!
>   After just **7 days** in private beta, we’ve already got 188 users who have asked 70 questions and written 152 answers.

No, Crypto.SE's private beta was quite a bit longer than that.

Comment: Should say [6 to 8 weeks](http://www.cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php) instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good catch. This is fixed now.

This part of Area 51 was written during the magical days of yesteryear, when private betas lasted exactly 7 days.